# Googles jQuery: Are There Avantages to Using It?

Tags: jquery

Are there any good reasons to pull Google's jQuery from their servers as opposed to using the one included with Wordpress?

I'm confused as to why I might want to use Google's library.  Doesn't Wordpress, with its frequent updates, keep the latest version?

Or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big advantages are the Google [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) and the client side caching of the library. Your visitor will probably have a version of the jquery library in the browsers cache already, so he doesn't have to re-download the script from the local version used by WordPress.

One big disadvantage by including the library from the cloud: You have to trust Google.

Comment: Doesn't Google still use "do no evil" as it's company mantra? ;-)